# Telnet command for embeded system C

Tags: c, embedded, telnet

I have an embedded system that is programed in C. I need to do the equivalent to the DOS command Telnet. The idea is to test if the remote host is up and running.

I would like to have some orientation here like:

1. Open source project that I can use as a guide line (C language)
2. Some documentation on what the Telnet command does (so I can
   implement my own)

Thanks

**Update: Thank you for your valuable comments**

My system connects to a host via GPRS/Ethernet/dial up/Wifi (one of them). As a developer I check if the host is ok by using my windows laptop (with a Dial up modem, GPRS modem or whatever is needed) and running Telnet like this:

telnet 192.168.0.1 8000

(non real values)

If the host is ok I got the clean screen, otherwise I got an error. That's what I need to do in code, to be able to determine if the host is up and running by using a sort of DOS telnet client command in C.

This is done once, just to check communications, after this test is cleared the real info should be sent.

Comment: What features of telnet do you need? How are you connected to the embedded system? What peripherals are connected to the system? How much diskspace/battery life do you have?

Comment: Odds are you are not going to be able to create a full telnet client. Try running the DOS/Windows one and see the stuff it does to start.

Comment: Telnet is a DOS command? Huh! You would need a telnet **server*, not a **client** (that's what you most likely mean by "DOS command"). So read about telnet protocol, possibly have a look at open source servers how they do it (**observer the licenses, however - do not just modify them and use as closed source!**), and implement your own (it is very likely easier to start from scratch anyway for an embedded framework).

Comment: this may be a kickoff 
http://www.ultimaserial.com/avr_lwip_tcp.html

Comment: It is not clear whether the device in question is the client or server. Clarify.  Telnet was never a DOS command MS-DOS never even had native support for networking until *Windows 3.1 for Workgroups*.  You at least have a TCP/IP stack right?  If not then you need one - Telnet is a TCP/IP application layer protocol.  Most such stacks include Telnet in any case.

Comment: Determining whether a remote host is up and running requires only *Ping*; Telnet provides a remote terminal connection.